# Dynamically inject script tag pre </body>

Tags: node.js, http, webserver, node.js-connect

At the end of a request I would like to tap into the results that are `text/html` end inject `</body>` tag. Ideally this would tap in as low as possible - i.e. HTTP module or at worst Connect.

I'm trying to create a package that will be used for debugging and when debugging is enabled, I want the scripts to be injected. Getting this in as low as possible just means that the package I'm working on is as compatible as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to monkey patch ServerResponse.end like so:

```
var http = require('http');

var oldEnd = http.ServerResponse.prototype.end,
    RE_CONTYPE_HTML = /Content-Type: text\/html/i;
http.ServerResponse.prototype.end = function(data, encoding) {
  if (RE_CONTYPE_HTML.test(this._header)) {
    if (data)
      this.write(data, encoding);
    this.write('<script>window.onload = function(){ alert("Hello World!"); };</script>', 'ascii');
    oldEnd.call(this);
  } else
    oldEnd.call(this, data, encoding);
};

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.end('<h1>Greetings from node.js!</h1>');
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've done something very similar to what you have here except that I've taped into the `data` arg of the `end` method. Can you see any issues in this?

Comment: I would think monkey patching end() would be better since you know at that point there's not going to be any more html coming through and it's safe to then append any script or other html tags.